# R Plotly choropleth map blank

Tags: r, plotly

Here is [a dropbox link to my data csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8otn4h5tk40cov2/wvs_ag.csv?dl=0).

I'm trying to make a Plotly choropleth map in R. I mirror the code from the Plotly example page as follows:

```
wvs_ag = read.csv("wvs_ag.csv")

l = list(color = toRGB("grey"), width = 0.5)

g = list(
  showframe = FALSE,
  showcoastlines = FALSE,
  showland = TRUE,
  projection = list(type = 'Mercator')
)

p = plot_geo(wvs_ag) %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~Agree_w, color = ~Agree_w, colors = 'Blues',
    text = ~Country_Code.p, locations = ~Country_Code.p, marker = list(line = l)) %>%
  colorbar(title = 'Agree_w') %>%
  layout(
    title = 'Title',
    geo = g
  )
```

However, this generates a blank map for me, with only the scale visible on the right side. How can I make the map appear?

(Side note: I don't know the exact country codes Plotly accepts. My original data had one set of country codes, so I simply merged it with the data in the Plotly example page and used their county codes.)

Edit: Here is the sessioninfo() output:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.2-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10      lattice_0.20-35   tidyr_0.6.1       viridisLite_0.2.0 digest_0.6.12    
 [6] dplyr_0.5.0       assertthat_0.1    grid_3.3.3        plyr_1.8.4        R6_2.2.0         
[11] jsonlite_1.3      gtable_0.2.0      DBI_0.6-1         magrittr_1.5      scales_0.4.1     
[16] httr_1.2.1        ggplot2_2.2.1     lazyeval_0.2.0    tools_3.3.3       htmlwidgets_0.8  
[21] purrr_0.2.2       munsell_0.4.3     yaml_2.1.14       base64enc_0.1-3   colorspace_1.3-2 
[26] htmltools_0.3.5   plotly_4.5.6      tibble_1.3.0
```

Comment: Your filename in `read.csv' and in your dropbox account don't match. But except for that the code produces a nice result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH0T1.png

Comment: Ah, sorry. Just fixed the read.csv typo. Hmm, weird that you're able to produce a map and I'm not when running the same code. I don't know why that is.

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes when the R-Studio plot viewer has to switch back and forth between different kinds of output it sometimes gets "stuck" and only shows a blank screen. Could be a R-Studio bug, or a htmlwidget bug in whatever you are using. Maybe this is that, or related to it. I will pay more attention next time it happens and try and find a repro.

Comment: Also in cases like this, where you don't get results and someone else does, you should append the `sessionInfo()` results to your question.